# Simple port forwarding for UDP stream on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, port-forwarding, iptables, streaming

I'm trying to use ncat (form the nmap distro for Windows) to simply forward a UDP stream.

Example:  A video stream can be received on port 5444.  I want to forward that stream to another machine (say 192.168.10.10) on port 5555.

I found where this can be done easily for TCP connections (i.e.

> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5444 listenaddress=192.168.10.9 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.10.10

), but I don't see how to do it for UDP.

Socat is the obvious solution in Linux, but I must use Windows.

I tried this:

> ncat -l -u 5444 | ncat -u 192.168.10.10 5555

But performance is so abysmal it is unusable.  I think I'm barking up the wrong tree with ncat.

This has GOT to be easy, but I'm a newb when it comes to iptables and the like (where I suspect the answer lies).  Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Windows does not a built-in tool for UDP forwarding. Try the free [Simple UDP proxy/pipe](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I found an 'easy' Windows-based solution with no third-party dependencies.  It is to enable RRAS NAT on a Windows Server OS.  Then,

> netsh routing ip nat add portmapping "Ethernet" udp 0.0.0.0 5444 192.168.10.10 5555

where "Ethernet" is the name of the NIC that is the "public interface" with NAT enabled in Routing and Remote Assistance.

When properly configured, the following command results in the output that follows:

```
>netsh routing ip nat show interface

NAT Ethernet Configuration
---------------------------
Mode              : Private Interface


NAT Static Port Mapping Configuration
-------------------------------------
Protocol          : UDP
Public address    : 0.0.0.0
Public port       : 5444
Private address   : 192.168.10.10
Private port      : 5555
```

harrymc's suggestion of sudpproxy was a good answer as well, but for my application, the additional overhead of the native Windows approach is less of a drawback than the dependency on a third-party tool.